# How to completely stop SKAction Easing

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

BY default an SKAction will ease in and out of the the action. I would like to completely turn off all easing. The .timingMode property seems to only have limited options and there doesn't seem to be a way of completely turning easing off. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions do not perform easing by default. The default timing mode is linear interpolation (ie no easing), see: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKAction/timingMode